# Windows 8 Metro apps no longer animating

Tags: windows-8, modern-ui

I have a strange problem with windows 8

Usually when you open up a metro app, there will be a swivel animation of the tile expanding to the size of the screen, this animation no longer exists.

Also when switching between metro apps there is usually a sliding animation from one application to another this also no longer works.

While this is all just aesthetics and does not affect the overall running of the applications, I am just curious if this is a known issue and whether there is a way to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Control Panel -> Ease of Access Center -> Optimize Visual Display -> Turn off all unnecessary animations (uncheck). That disables pretty much everything, including the minimizing of desktop applications.

Also try Control Panel (all) -> Performance Information and Tools -> Adjust Visual Effects.

Comment: Thanks the first instruction worked, I had to check it, press apply then uncheck it again for it to work again, very odd.